# Axis title setting

Tags: excel, applescript, excel-2008

How to apply a vertical axis title as rotated title, Horizontal title, vertical title in Excel 2008 using AppleScript.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  tell worksheet 1 of active workbook 
     set ochart to chart of chart object "chartname"
       tell ochart
         set cattitle to gat axis of ochart axis type category axis which axis primary axis
               tell cattitle 
                   set has title to 1
                    ----- how to apply a title position (Horizontal,Rotated,Vertical title)
               end tell
          end tell
   end tell
```

I am not find a apple script command in apple excel dictionary which helpful. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
        set ochart1 to chart of chart object 1
        tell ochart1
            set valueA to get axis axis type value axis which axis primary axis
            tell valueA
                set it's has title to true
                set axis title text of it's axis title to "Rotated"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Hi, My question is how to apply a rotated title and vertical title on chart. your script is create a title with horizontal position with text "Your Title". I want to create a title with rotated position. see a picture.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks for the picture. Try the edited version.